# Godot root motion is calculated incorrectly?

Tags: animation, godot-4, root-motion

I'm trying to set up root motion in Godot but it's not giving the expected result.

This is the original animation:

[image: The base animation]

After setting up the AnimationTree to use the root bone, the character correctly stays in place, but the interpreted movement is not at all what it should be:

[image: Setting the root motion with a RootMotionView]

As you can see, it just wiggles side to side (which is an expected part of the animation), but it doesn't move forward.

I can't figure out what could be causing it. As I understand it the motion is calculated by looking at the location keyframes of the root bone, so what could be going wrong?

Edit: I notice that the RootMotionView floor drops away if I uncheck "Zero Y", which doesn't happen with the model I have that's working correctly:

[image]

Comment: I think you should post this as an issue in GitHub, here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just posted it as an issue there.

Comment: @frnsys was there any resolution to your issue? Adding a link here would help future readers follow up and learn from any comments posted there.

Answer (score -1):

this is normal, you need to code the kinematic or character controller to move your character about

the function get_root_motion_position gives how much to move_and_slide each frame.... myself i'm still trying to get the rotation correct this depends on the model animations i believe

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the `RootMotionView` node is meant to show the root motion without needing to code up the full character controller.